# Convert Yaml from GitLab to azure devops

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I want to convert Yaml pipeline from Gitlab to Azure DevOps. The problem is I did not have experience with GitLab before. This is yaml.
Is .package_deploy template for job? And is image it a pool or I need to use for this Docker task?
And before_script: means I need to create a task before task with docker?

```
    variables:
          myVar: "Var"
       
    stages:
      - deploy
    
    .package_deploy:
      image: registry.gitlab.com/docker-images/$myVar:latest
      stage: build
      script:
        - cd src
        - echo "Output file name is set to $OUTPUT_FILE_NAME"
        - echo $OUTPUT_FILE_NAME > version.txt
        - az login --service-principal -u $ARM_CLIENT_ID -p $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $ARM_TENANT_ID

    
    dev_package_deploy:
      extends: .package_deploy
      stage: deploy
      before_script:
        - export FOLDER=$FOLDER_DEV
        - timestampSuffix=$(date -u "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
        - export OUTPUT_FILE_NAME=${myVar}-${timestampSuffix}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}.tar.gz
      when: manual
    
    demo_package_deploy:
      extends: .package_deploy
      stage: deploy
      before_script:
        - export FOLDER=$FOLDER_DEMO
        - timestampSuffix=$(date -u "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
        - export OUTPUT_FILE_NAME=${myVar}-${timestampSuffix}.tar.gz
      when: manual
      only:
        refs:
          - master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.package_deploy:` is a 'hidden job' that you can use with the [`extends`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) keyword. Itself, it does not create any job. It's a way to avoid repeating yourself in other job definitions.

`before_script` really is no different from `script` except that they're two different keys. The effect is that `before_script` + `script` includes all the script steps in the job.

```yaml
before_script:
 - one
 - two
script:
 - three
 - four
```

Is the same as:

```yaml
script:
 - one
 - two
 - three
 - four
```

`image:` defines the docker container in which the job runs. In this way, it is very similar to a `pool` you would define in ADO. But if you want things to run close to thee way it does in GitLab, you probably want to define it as [`container:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops) in ADO.